# A dashboard for my university's commonly used resources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This is my first big JavaScript project and I wanted to know what I could improve in terms of coding practices and design. It is a Chrome extension made for Vanderbilt students (VandyTab) that takes over the new tab and shows the time, bus timings, what restaurants are open and so on.

```
var jumbotron, supporting, data, header;
var totalCount = 6;
var preCompiledRegex = /<li>Bus(.*?)<\/li>/g;

// bus keeps track of bus asked for
// menuLevel keeps track of the menu level of the VandyVan table
var bus;
var menuLevel = 0;
var tday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var tmonth = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var myname = localStorage.name;

var randdininghall = ["1", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "16", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "16", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "AM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "10", "0", "AM", "14", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "10", "0", "AM", "14", "0", "PM", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM"];

var chefJames = ["2", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "16", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM"];

var theCommons = ["3", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "10", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "10", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var theKitchen = ["5", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Monday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Tuesday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Wednesday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Thursday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Friday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Closed", "Sunday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Monday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM"];

var thePub = ["4", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "15", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];

var lastDrop = ["15", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "15", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];

var subsTowers = ["8", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Sunday", "9", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Sunday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM"];

var subsHighland = ["9", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "9", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Saturday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "9", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Sunday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "0", "PM", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM"];

var rotiki = ["10", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var grins = ["11", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "8", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];

var suzieBlairFgh = ["12", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Friday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM"];

var suzieMrb = ["13", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM"];

var foodForThought = ["14", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "8", "0", "PM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "14", "0", "PM", "20", "0", "PM", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var bambooBistro = ["7", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var pi = ["6", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "17", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "17", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];


function changeIt() {
    "use strict";
//specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    var num, mycreds, names;

    num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);
    document.body.background = 'img/back' + num + '.jpg';
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";// Background repeat


    mycreds = [
        {
            text: "https://flic.kr/p/xiKVUg"
        },
        {
            text: "https://flic.kr/p/fLgdj1"
        },
        {
            text: "https://flic.kr/p/nq2oNX"
        },
        {
            text: "https://flic.kr/p/xTpMxH"
        },
        {
            text: "https://flic.kr/p/dpNYUF"

        },
        {
            text: "https://flic.kr/p/xe2Xmg"
        }
    ];

    names = [
        {
            text: "Daniel Dubois"
        },
        {
            text: "Daniel Dubois"
        },
        {
            text: "Daniel Dubois"
        },
        {
            text: "Daniel Dubois"
        },
        {
            text: "365@VU"
        },
        {
            text: "Daniel Bubois"
        }
    ];


    document.getElementById("cred").innerHTML = '<a href="' + mycreds[num - 1].text + '"><b>' + names[num - 1].text + '</b></a>';
}

function getTime() {
    "use strict";
    var d, nmonth, ndate, nyear, nhour, nmin, nsec, ap;

    d = new Date();
    nmonth = d.getMonth();
    ndate = d.getDate();
    nyear = d.getYear();

    if (nyear < 1000) {
        nyear += 1900;
    }
    nhour = d.getHours();
    nmin = d.getMinutes();
    nsec = d.getSeconds();

    if (nhour === 0) {
        ap = " AM";
        nhour = 12;
    } else if (nhour < 12) {
        ap = " AM";
    } else if (nhour === 12) {
        ap = " PM";
    } else if (nhour > 12) {
        ap = " PM";
        nhour -= 12;
    }

    if (nmin <= 9) {
        nmin = "0" + nmin;
    }
    if (nsec <= 9) {
        nsec = "0" + nsec;
    }

    document.getElementById('clockbox1').innerHTML = nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec;
}

function getClock() {
    "use strict";
    var d, nday, nmonth, ndate, nhour;
    d = new Date();
    nhour = d.getHours();
    nday = d.getDay();
    nmonth = d.getMonth();
    ndate = d.getDate();

    if (nhour <= 6) {
        document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = "Good evening, " + myname + ".";
    } else if (nhour <= 12) {
        document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = "Good morning, " + myname + ".";
    } else if (nhour <= 17) {
        document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = "Good afternoon, " + myname + ".";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = "Good evening, " + myname + ".";
    }

    //document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = tday[nday] + ", " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + ndate + myname;
}

function displayTime(displayOpen, x, y, ap, id) {
    "use strict";
    //open/close image
    var image;

    //formats hours and minutes
    if (y <= 9) {
        y = "0" + y;
    }
    if (x === 0) {
        x = 12;
    } else if (x > 12) {
        x -= 12;
    }

    //displays image and formatted time on table
    //if display open === true, the dining is closed and table displays "Open @..."
    if (displayOpen === true) {
        image = document.getElementById("open" + id);
        image.src = "img/closed.png";
        document.getElementById(id).textContent = "Opens @ " + x + ":" + y + " " + ap;
    } else {
        image = document.getElementById("open" + id);
        image.src = "img/open.png";
        document.getElementById(id).textContent = "Closes @ " + x + ":" + y + " " + ap;
    }
}

function displayDay(day, id) {
    "use strict";
    var image;
    image = document.getElementById("open" + id);
    image.src = "img/closed.png";
    document.getElementById(id).textContent = "Opens on " + day;

}

function setDining(a) {
    "use strict";

    //declare variables
    var d, nhour, nmin, nsec, nday, ap, rand, i;
    d = new Date();
    nhour = d.getHours();
    nmin = d.getMinutes();
    nsec = d.getSeconds();
    nday = d.getDay();

    //rand is the passed array, i is counter
    rand = a;
    i = 1;

    //looks for days through rand array
    while (i < rand.length) {

        //if the day matches
        if (rand[i] === tday[nday]) {

            //if it is after the opening hour
            if (nhour > parseInt(rand[i + 1], 10)) {
                 // if it is before the closing hour 
                if (nhour < parseInt(rand[i + 4], 10)) {
                       //***It is open!!!
                    displayTime(false, rand[i + 4], rand[i + 5], rand[i + 6], rand[0]);
                    break;
                } else if (nhour === parseInt(rand[i + 4], 10)) {
                     //if it is the closing hour, check to see if before minute of closing
                    if (nmin < parseInt(rand[i + 5], 10)) {
                         //***It is open!!!
                        displayTime(false, rand[i + 4], rand[i + 5], rand[i + 6], rand[0]);
                        break;
                    } else {
                         //***It is closed!!!
                        if (rand[i + 7] === tday[nday]) {
                            i = i + 1;
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (rand[i + 8] === "Closed") {
                            displayDay(rand[i + 9], rand[0]);
                        } else if (rand[i + 7] === "Closed") {
                            displayDay(rand[i + 8], rand[0]);
                        } else {
                            displayTime(true, rand[i + 8], rand[i + 9], rand[i + 10], rand[0]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                     //***It is closed!!!
                    if (rand[i + 7] === tday[nday]) {
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (rand[i + 8] === "Closed") {
                        displayDay(rand[i + 9], rand[0]);
                    } else if (rand[i + 7] === "Closed") {
                        displayDay(rand[i + 8], rand[0]);
                    } else {
                        displayTime(true, rand[i + 8], rand[i + 9], rand[i + 10], rand[0]);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            } else if (nhour === parseInt(rand[i + 1], 10)) {
                if (nmin >= parseInt(rand[i + 2], 10)) {
                     //***It is open!!!
                    displayTime(false, rand[i + 4], rand[i + 5], rand[i + 6], rand[0]);
                    break;
                } else {
                  //***It is closed!!!
                    if (rand[i + 7] === tday[nday]) {
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (rand[i + 8] === "Closed") {
                        displayDay(rand[i + 9], rand[0]);
                    } else if (rand[i + 7] === "Closed") {
                        displayDay(rand[i + 8], rand[0]);
                    } else {
                        displayTime(true, rand[i + 8], rand[i + 9], rand[i + 10], rand[0]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                //***It is closed!!!
                if (rand[i + 7] === tday[nday]) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;
                }

                if (rand[i + 8] === "Closed") {
                    displayDay(rand[i + 9], rand[0]);
                } else if (rand[i + 7] === "Closed") {
                    displayDay(rand[i + 8], rand[0]);
                } else {
                    displayTime(true, rand[i + 8], rand[i + 9], rand[i + 10], rand[0]);
                }
                break;
            }
        } else if (rand[i] === "Closed") {
            if (rand[i + 1] === "Closed") {
                //checks if there are two closed days in a row
                //checks if after closed is today so loop can continue or if today is the day before it opens
                if (rand[i + 2] === tday[nday] || tday[nday + 1] === rand[i + 2]) {
                    i = i + 1;
                } else {
                    displayDay(rand[i + 2], rand[0]);
                    break;
                }
                //displayTime(true, rand[i + 3], rand[i + 4], rand[i + 5], rand[0]);
                //i = i + 1;

            } else {
                //if there aren't, don't need to add 1 more to i
                displayTime(true, rand[i + 2], rand[i + 3], rand[i + 4], rand[0]);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            //if day doesn't match and is not closed, go to next element of the array
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}



function fade(element) {
    "use strict";
    var timer, op;
    op = 1;  // initial opacity
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}

function unfade(element) {
    "use strict";
    var timer, op;
    op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 10);
}

document.getElementById("nameSubmit").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    "use strict";
    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    }
    //e.preventDefault(); // sometimes useful

     //Enter is pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        header = document.querySelector(".header");
        //header.style.marginTop = "0px";
        fade(header);
        //document.getElementByName("nameSubmit").disabled = "true";
        jumbotron = document.querySelector(".jumbotron");
        //jumbotron.style.opacity = 1;
        supporting = document.querySelector(".supporting");
        //supporting.style.opacity = 1;
        data = document.querySelector(".data");
        //data.style.opacity = 1;
        myname = document.getElementById("nameSubmit").value;
        localStorage.name = myname;
        getClock();
        setInterval(getClock, 1000);
        getTime();
        setInterval(getTime, 1000);
        setDining(randdininghall);
        setDining(chefJames);
        setDining(theCommons);
        setDining(thePub);
        setDining(theKitchen);
        setDining(lastDrop);
        setDining(subsHighland);
        setDining(subsTowers);
        setDining(suzieBlairFgh);
        setDining(suzieMrb);
        setDining(rotiki);
        setDining(grins);
        setDining(foodForThought);
        setDining(bambooBistro);
        setDining(pi);

        header.style.display = "none";
        unfade(jumbotron);
        unfade(supporting);
        unfade(data);

    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    "use strict";
    var nameChange;

    nameChange = document.getElementById('clockbox');
    nameChange.addEventListener('click', function () {
        header = document.querySelector(".header");
        jumbotron = document.querySelector(".jumbotron");
        supporting = document.querySelector(".supporting");
        data = document.querySelector(".data");
        jumbotron.style.opacity = 0;
        supporting.style.opacity = 0;
        data.style.opacity = 0;
        header.style.opacity = 0;
        header.style.display = "block";
        header.style.marginTop = "3.5em";
        unfade(header);
    });
});

function vandyTimes(link) {
    "use strict";
    var van1, van2, van3, van4, van5, van6, van7, van8, van9, van10, van11, van12, van13, d, nhour;
    d = new Date();
    nhour = d.getHours();
    van1 = document.getElementById('van1');
    van2 = document.getElementById('van2');
    van3 = document.getElementById('van3');
    van4 = document.getElementById('van4');
    van5 = document.getElementById('van5');
    van6 = document.getElementById('van6');
    van7 = document.getElementById('van7');
    van8 = document.getElementById('van8');
    van9 = document.getElementById('van9');
    van10 = document.getElementById('van10');
    van11 = document.getElementById('van11');
    van12 = document.getElementById('van12');
    van13 = document.getElementById('van13');

    if (nhour >= 17) {
    $.ajax({
            url: link,
            success: function(data) {
                var matches = data.match(preCompiledRegex);  // regex parse to find relevant tag
                //document.getElementById('vanB').innerHTML = matches;
                var message = '';
                if (matches === null) {
                    //message = 'No arrival times available!!!';
                    document.getElementById('van2').setAttribute("style","height:127px");
                van3.style.display = "none";
                van4.style.display = "none";
                van5.style.display = "none";
                van6.style.display = "none";
                van7.style.display = "none";
                van8.style.display = "none";
                van9.style.display = "none";
                van10.style.display = "none";
                van11.style.display = "none";
                van12.style.display = "none";
                van13.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('vanB').innerHTML = "No arrival times are available.";
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                        matches[i] = matches[i].substring(4, matches[i].length-5);
                        message += matches[i] + "<br/>";
                    }
                    document.getElementById('running1').setAttribute("style","width:0px");
                    document.getElementById('vanB').setAttribute("style","width:300px");
                    document.getElementById('vanB').innerHTML = message;
                    document.getElementById('van2').setAttribute("style","height:127px");
                van3.style.display = "none";
                van4.style.display = "none";
                van5.style.display = "none";
                van6.style.display = "none";
                van7.style.display = "none";
                van8.style.display = "none";
                van9.style.display = "none";
                van10.style.display = "none";
                van11.style.display = "none";
                van12.style.display = "none";
                van13.style.display = "none";
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                document.getElementById('vanB').textContent = "No arrival times available.";
                document.getElementById('van2').setAttribute("style","height:127px");
                van3.style.display = "none";
                van4.style.display = "none";
                van5.style.display = "none";
                van6.style.display = "none";
                van7.style.display = "none";
                van8.style.display = "none";
                van9.style.display = "none";
                van10.style.display = "none";
                van11.style.display = "none";
                van12.style.display = "none";
                van13.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('vanB').textContent = "No arrival times available.";
                document.getElementById('van2').setAttribute("style","height:127px");
                van3.style.display = "none";
                van4.style.display = "none";
                van5.style.display = "none";
                van6.style.display = "none";
                van7.style.display = "none";
                van8.style.display = "none";
                van9.style.display = "none";
                van10.style.display = "none";
                van11.style.display = "none";
                van12.style.display = "none";
                van13.style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    "use strict";
    var van1, van2, van3, van4, van5, van6, van7, van8, van9, van10, van11, van12, van13, black, gold, red, vanA, redImage, goldImage, blackImage, running1, running2, running3, d, nhour;

    d = new Date();
    nhour = d.getHours();

    black = false;
    gold = false;
    red = false;
    van1 = document.getElementById('van1');
    van2 = document.getElementById('van2');
    van3 = document.getElementById('van3');
    van4 = document.getElementById('van4');
    van5 = document.getElementById('van5');
    van6 = document.getElementById('van6');
    van7 = document.getElementById('van7');
    van8 = document.getElementById('van8');
    van9 = document.getElementById('van9');
    van10 = document.getElementById('van10');
    van11 = document.getElementById('van11');
    van12 = document.getElementById('van12');
    van13 = document.getElementById('van13');
    running1 = document.getElementById('running1');
    running2 = document.getElementById('running2');
    running3 = document.getElementById('running3');

    //onload
    if (menuLevel === 0) {
        if (nhour >= 17 || nhour <= 5) {
            running1.textContent = "Status: Running";
            running2.textContent = "Status: Running";
            running3.textContent = "Status: Running";
        } else {
            running1.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
            running2.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
            running3.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
        }
        van1.style.display = "none";
        van5.style.display = "none";
        van6.style.display = "none";
        van7.style.display = "none";
        van8.style.display = "none";
        van9.style.display = "none";
        van10.style.display = "none";
        van11.style.display = "none";
        van12.style.display = "none";
        van13.style.display = "none";
        van2.style.height = "54px";
        van3.style.height = "54px";
        van4.style.height = "52px";
        goldImage = document.getElementById("perimeter");
        goldImage.src = "img/goldvan.png";
        redImage = document.getElementById("reverse");
        redImage.src = "img/redvan.png";
        blackImage = document.getElementById("main");
        blackImage.src = "img/blackvan.png";
    }

    van1.addEventListener('click', function () {
        //back to main menu
        if (menuLevel === 1) {

        if (nhour >= 17 || nhour <= 5) {
            running1.textContent = "Status: Running";
            running2.textContent = "Status: Running";
            running3.textContent = "Status: Running";
        } else {
            running1.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
            running2.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
            running3.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
        }

        van1.style.display = "none";
        van5.style.display = "none";
        van6.style.display = "none";
        van7.style.display = "none";
        van8.style.display = "none";
        van9.style.display = "none";
        van10.style.display = "none";
        van11.style.display = "none";
        van12.style.display = "none";
        van13.style.display = "none";

        black = false;
        gold = false;
        red = false;

        goldImage.src = "img/goldvan.png";
        redImage.src = "img/redvan.png";
        blackImage.src = "img/blackvan.png";

        document.getElementById('van2').setAttribute("style","height:54px");
        document.getElementById('van3').setAttribute("style","height:54px");
        document.getElementById('van4').setAttribute("style","height:52px");

        document.getElementById('vanB').innerHTML = "Main Route (Black)";
        document.getElementById('vanC').textContent = "Perimeter Route (Gold)";
        document.getElementById('vanD').textContent = "Reverse Route (Red)";

        document.getElementById('running1').setAttribute("style","width:150px");

        menuLevel = menuLevel - 1;    
        } else if (menuLevel === 2) {
             if (nhour >= 17 || nhour <= 5) {
            running1.textContent = "Status: Running";
            running2.textContent = "Status: Running";
            running3.textContent = "Status: Running";
        } else {
            running1.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
            running2.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
            running3.textContent = "Status: Not Running";
        }

        van1.style.display = "none";
        van5.style.display = "none";
        van6.style.display = "none";
        van7.style.display = "none";
        van8.style.display = "none";
        van9.style.display = "none";
        van10.style.display = "none";
        van11.style.display = "none";
        van12.style.display = "none";
        van13.style.display = "none";

        black = false;
        gold = false;
        red = false;

        goldImage.src = "img/goldvan.png";
        redImage.src = "img/redvan.png";
        blackImage.src = "img/blackvan.png";

        document.getElementById('van2').setAttribute("style","height:54px");
        document.getElementById('van3').setAttribute("style","height:54px");
        document.getElementById('van4').setAttribute("style","height:52px");

        document.getElementById('vanB').innerHTML = "Main Route (Black)";
        document.getElementById('vanC').textContent = "Perimeter Route (Gold)";
        document.getElementById('vanD').textContent = "Reverse Route (Red)";

        document.getElementById('running1').setAttribute("style","width:150px");

        menuLevel = menuLevel - 2;
        }
    });

    //main route
    van2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 0) {

            document.getElementById('vanA').textContent = "< Back";
            van1.style.display = "inline-block";

            van2.style.display = "none";
            van3.style.display = "none";
            van4.style.display = "none";

            van2.style.display = "inline";
            van3.style.display = "inline";
            van4.style.display = "inline";

            van5.style.display = "inline-block";
            van6.style.display = "inline-block";
            van7.style.display = "inline-block";
            van8.style.display = "inline-block";
            van9.style.display = "inline-block";
            document.getElementById('vanB').textContent = "Branscomb Quad";
            document.getElementById('vanC').textContent = "Carmichael Towers";
            document.getElementById('vanD').textContent = "Kissam-Kirkland";
            document.getElementById('vanE').textContent = "21st near Terrace Place";
            document.getElementById('vanF').textContent = "Wesley Place";
            document.getElementById('vanG').textContent = "1801 Edgehill";
            document.getElementById('vanH').textContent = "Hank Ingram";
            document.getElementById('vanI').textContent = "Highland Quad";

            blackImage.src = "";
            goldImage.src = "";
            redImage.src = "";

            running1.textContent = "";
            running2.textContent = "";
            running3.textContent = "";

            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
            black = true;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            document.getElementById('vanB').innerHTML = "No arrival times are available.";
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/263473/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/263473/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && red === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1291/direction/1858/stops/263473/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    //perimeter route
    van3.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 0) {
            document.getElementById('vanA').textContent = "< Back";
            van1.style.display = "inline-block";

            van2.style.display = "none";
            van3.style.display = "none";
            van4.style.display = "none";

            van2.style.display = "inline";
            van3.style.display = "inline";
            van4.style.display = "inline";

            van5.style.display = "inline-block";
            van6.style.display = "inline-block";
            van7.style.display = "inline-block";
            van8.style.display = "inline-block";
            van9.style.display = "inline-block";
            van10.style.display = "inline-block";
            van11.style.display = "inline-block";
            van12.style.display = "inline-block";
            van13.style.display = "inline-block";
            document.getElementById('vanB').textContent = "Branscomb Quad";
            document.getElementById('vanC').textContent = "Carmichael Towers";
            document.getElementById('vanD').textContent = "Kissam-Kirkland";
            document.getElementById('vanE').textContent = "21st near Terrace Place";
            document.getElementById('vanF').textContent = "MRB3";
            document.getElementById('vanG').textContent = "North Hall";
            document.getElementById('vanH').textContent = "Blair";
            document.getElementById('vanI').textContent = "Highland Quad";
            document.getElementById('vanJ').textContent = "McGugin";
            document.getElementById('vanK').textContent = "V.U.P.D.";
            document.getElementById('vanL').textContent = "Barnes & Noble";
            document.getElementById('vanM').textContent = "Lupton";

            blackImage.src = "";
            goldImage.src = "";
            redImage.src = "";

            running1.textContent = "";
            running2.textContent = "";
            running3.textContent = "";

            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
            gold = true;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/263470/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/263470/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && red === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1291/direction/1858/stops/264041/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    //reverse route
    van4.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 0) {
            document.getElementById('vanA').textContent = "< Back";
            van1.style.display = "inline-block";

            van2.style.display = "none";
            van3.style.display = "none";
            van4.style.display = "none";

            van2.style.display = "inline";
            van3.style.display = "inline";
            van4.style.display = "inline";

            van5.style.display = "inline-block";
            van6.style.display = "inline-block";
            van7.style.display = "inline-block";

            document.getElementById('vanB').textContent = "Branscomb Quad";
            document.getElementById('vanC').textContent = "V.U.P.D.";
            document.getElementById('vanD').textContent = "Highland Quad";
            document.getElementById('vanE').textContent = "Blair";
            document.getElementById('vanF').textContent = "Hank Ingram";
            document.getElementById('vanG').textContent = "Carmichael Towers";

            blackImage.src = "";
            goldImage.src = "";
            redImage.src = "";

            running1.textContent = "";
            running2.textContent = "";
            running3.textContent = "";

            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
            red = true;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/1198824/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/1198824/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && red === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1291/direction/1858/stops/263444/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    van5.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/644873/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/644873/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && red === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1291/direction/1858/stops/1547179/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }

    });

    van6.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/1198825/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/1547177/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && red === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1291/direction/1858/stops/644903/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }

    });

    van7.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/1570180/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/1547178/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && red === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1291/direction/1858/stops/263470/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } 
    });

    van8.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/644903/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/1547179/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    van9.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && black === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1290/direction/1857/stops/263444/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        } else if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/263444/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    van10.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/1547180/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    van11.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/264041/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    van12.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/1547181/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });

    van13.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (menuLevel === 1 && gold === true) {
            vandyTimes("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.vandyvans.com/simple/routes/1289/direction/3021/stops/238066/pattern");
            menuLevel = menuLevel + 1;
        }
    });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    "use strict";
    var link1, link2, link3, link4,  link5, link6,  link7, link8, link9, link10,  link11, link12, link13, link14, link15;
    link1 = document.getElementById('link1');
    link2 = document.getElementById('link2');
    link3 = document.getElementById('link3');
    link4 = document.getElementById('link4');
    link5 = document.getElementById('link5');
    link6 = document.getElementById('link6');
    link7 = document.getElementById('link7');
    link8 = document.getElementById('link8');
    link9 = document.getElementById('link9');
    link10 = document.getElementById('link10');
    link11 = document.getElementById('link11');
    link12 = document.getElementById('link12');
    link13 = document.getElementById('link13');
    link14 = document.getElementById('link14');
    link15 = document.getElementById('link15');
    // onClick's logic below:
    link1.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/location/rand-dining-center/", "_self");
    });
    link2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/chef-james-bistro/", "_self");
    });
    link3.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/location/the-commons/", "_self");
    });
    link4.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/the-pub-at-overcup-oak/", "_self");
    });
    link5.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/the-kitchen/", "_self");
    });
    link6.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/pi/", "_self");
    });
    link7.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/bamboo-bistro/", "_self");
    });
    link8.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/rocket-subs-towers/", "_self");
    });
    link9.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/rocket-subs-morgan/", "_self");
    });
    link10.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/rotiki/", "_self");
    });
    link11.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/grins-vegetarian-cafe/", "_self");
    });
    link12.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/suzies-cafe/", "_self");
    });
    link13.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/suzies-cafe/", "_self");
    });
    link14.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/food-for-thought-cafe/", "_self");
    });
    link15.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/last-drop-coffee-shop/", "_self");
    });
});


window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    if (myname === undefined) {
        //document.getElementByName("nameSubmit").enabled = "true";
        changeIt();
        header = document.querySelector(".header");
        header.style.opacity = 0;
        unfade(header);
        jumbotron = document.querySelector(".jumbotron");
        jumbotron.style.opacity = 0;
        supporting = document.querySelector(".supporting");
        supporting.style.opacity = 0;
        data = document.querySelector(".data");
        data.style.opacity = 0;

    } else {
        header = document.querySelector(".header");
        header.style.marginTop = "0px";
        header.style.display = "none";
        jumbotron = document.querySelector(".jumbotron");
        jumbotron.style.opacity = 0;
        supporting = document.querySelector(".supporting");
        supporting.style.opacity = 0;
        data = document.querySelector(".data");
        data.style.opacity = 0;
        unfade(jumbotron);
        unfade(supporting);
        unfade(data);
        changeIt();
        getClock();
        setInterval(getClock, 1000);
        getTime();
        setInterval(getTime, 1000);
        setDining(randdininghall);
        setDining(chefJames);
        setDining(theCommons);
        setDining(thePub);
        setDining(theKitchen);
        setDining(lastDrop);
        setDining(subsHighland);
        setDining(subsTowers);
        setDining(suzieBlairFgh);
        setDining(suzieMrb);
        setDining(rotiki);
        setDining(grins);
        setDining(foodForThought);
        setDining(bambooBistro);
        setDining(pi);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is this all one file? It's huge. If you've never used a bundler like browserify or webpack consider looking into it, as it will make your project considerably more manageable and help you split your concerns.

Answer (score 5):

```
var randdininghall = ["1", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "16", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "16", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "AM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "10", "0", "AM", "14", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "10", "0", "AM", "14", "0", "PM", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM"];

var chefJames = ["2", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "16", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "30", "PM"];

var theCommons = ["3", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "10", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "10", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var theKitchen = ["5", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Monday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Tuesday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Wednesday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Thursday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Friday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Closed", "Sunday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "10", "0", "AM", "Monday", "17", "30", "PM", "19", "30", "PM"];

var thePub = ["4", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "15", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];

var lastDrop = ["15", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "15", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];

var subsTowers = ["8", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Sunday", "9", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Sunday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM"];

var subsHighland = ["9", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "9", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Saturday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "9", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Sunday", "11", "0", "AM", "19", "0", "PM", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "10", "30", "AM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "22", "0", "PM"];

var rotiki = ["10", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var grins = ["11", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "8", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];

var suzieBlairFgh = ["12", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Friday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "7", "30", "AM", "14", "30", "PM"];

var suzieMrb = ["13", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Tuesday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Wednesday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Thursday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Friday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "7", "0", "AM", "16", "30", "PM"];

var foodForThought = ["14", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "8", "0", "PM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Sunday", "14", "0", "PM", "20", "0", "PM", "Monday", "8", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var bambooBistro = ["7", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "15", "0", "PM", "Closed", "Closed", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "20", "0", "PM"];

var pi = ["6", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Tuesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Wednesday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Thursday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Friday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM", "Saturday", "17", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Sunday", "17", "0", "PM", "21", "0", "PM", "Monday", "11", "0", "AM", "21", "0", "PM"];
```

First is this monstrosity. I'm not sure what the values mean. Arrays are normally used as "a list of same-type items". Not really sure what how "6" relates to "Monday" or "0" is to "AM". It's best if you had a list of objects.

A closer inspection, it looks like opening and closing times of different locations. I would suggest you do it like:

```
var establishmentBusinessHours = [{
  name: 'Bamboo Bistro',
  hours: [{
    // You can start the array as "Sunday" (index 0)
    open: '0000',
    close: '0000',
  },{
    open: '1100',
    close: '2100'
  }]
},{
  name: 'The Pub',
  hours: []
}]
```

---

```
function getTime() {
  "use strict";
  var d, nmonth, ndate, nyear, nhour, nmin, nsec, ap;

  d = new Date();
  nmonth = d.getMonth();
  ndate = d.getDate();
  nyear = d.getYear();
```

You might want to consider using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for getting time. It's a rather robust library for manipulating and formatting time. In this case, the code for get time is like a call away:

```
function getTime(){
  return moment().format('HH:mm:ss AA');
}
```

The greeter would be something like:

```
function getGreeting(name){
  var hour = moment().hour();
  var greeting = (IF hour IS 0000 - 1159) ? 'morning'
               : (IF hour IS 1200 - 1759) ? 'afternoon'
               : (IF hour IS 1800 - 2359) ? 'evening'
               : 'day';
  return `Good ${greeting}, ${name}`;
}
```

The `${}` are part of [JS template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) by the way. Relatively new API but really handy in avoiding string concatenation.

---

Now when you prefix `get` or `set` to functions, by convention, people normally expect something from `get*` or expect some mutation of something with `set*`. If you're not getting a value, I'd avoid using `get`. If you're not setting, I'd avoid putting `set`.

In the case of `getClock` and `getTime`, they're more like rendering. `renderTime` and `renderGreeting` would be more appropriate, respectively.

---

```
function displayTime(displayOpen, x, y, ap, id) {
  "use strict";
  //open/close image
  var image;
```

I'd avoid naming your variables this way. What does `x`, `y`, `ap` all mean? If you were to take the next 2 weeks on a cruise, drink a lot of alcohol and get wrecked, I bet when you come back to continue work on this, you wouldn't even have a clue what these things are.

Name variables verbosely. Extra keystrokes and characters are better than time and hair lost. (ever wonder why most programmers go bald? :D)

---

```
function fade(element) {
  "use strict";
  var timer, op;
  op = 1; // initial opacity
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op <= 0.1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
  }, 50);
}

function unfade(element) {
  "use strict";
  var timer, op;
  op = 0.1; // initial opacity
  element.style.display = 'block';
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, 10);
}
```

Consider NOT using JS to write your styles. Use JS for behavior. Visual flares like fading is the job of CSS. In this case, the behavior bit is just the change in state from visible to not visible (or vice versa). Fading is just a visual effect in result of the change in state.

State can be indicated by adding/removing classes on the element. In the following example, I'm using jQuery to add/remove `fading-text--visible`. The presence of the class tells the browser to make it visible (`opacity:1`) and the absence makes it invisible (`opacity:0`). The fading is done in CSS.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  // I'll cheat a bit here and use jQuery
  $('.fading-text').toggleClass('fading-text--visible');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.fading-text{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.fading-text--visible{
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fading-text fading-text--visible">This is some text that should fade in and out</div>
```

A lot of things can be transitioned. Most numeric properties can be transitioned, like margins, paddings, top, left, bottom, right. This means movement can simply be an effect of JS updating the position from initial to final.

The [BEM](https://en.bem.info/) naming convention of classes is also handy in this case. BEM means "Block Element Modifier". You can think of "Block" as a widget, and "Element" as an element inside the widget. We are interested in "Modifier" as it modifies whatever styles the Block and Element has. In this case, our modifier `fading-text--visible` changes the `opacity` value originally set in the `fading-text` class, essentially *modifying* `fading-text`.

---

```
link4.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open("http://campusdining.vanderbilt.edu/restaurant/the-pub-at-overcup-oak/", "_self");
});
```

Consider using real links instead. The same effect can be done with:

```
<a href="PATH HERE">text</a>
```

If you want it to open in a new window, add `target="_blank"` to the attributes.

---

Now most of your code is merely toggling states, visibility, DOM manipulation etc. Consider using jQuery to reduce the vanilla verbosity. Even further, try using a framework. ANY framework will do. For instance, building [a simple clock in Ractive](http://jsfiddle.net/0vwgtfkt/1/) only takes a few lines.

```
var Clock = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    The time is {{ date.getHours() }}:{{ date.getMinutes() }}:{{ date.getSeconds() }}
  `,
  onrender: function(){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.set('date', new Date());
    }, 1000);
  }
});

new Clock({
  el: 'body',
  append: true
});
```

This example is inefficient (creating `Date` objects regularly) but to the point is frameworks abstract pretty much everything for you. You don't see DOM changing code, just logic needed to run things.

A React version looks similar, except instead of `template` and `onrender`, you'll have `render` with JSX and a `onComponentDidMount` respectively. An Angular directive will also have the same form, except you'll have an Angular template and instead of `onrender`, you have `link` (or `controller`) respectively.

Frameworks have also moved into the "component" way of building things. This means you build a big app comprised of small widgets called "components". This means a dashboard with a clock, a greeter, a menu list, a business hours list won't be one big blob of code. Each widget can be developed independently and once done, you can just pop them in the page.

```
<div class="main-content">
  <Clock format="24" />
  <BusSchedules />
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <Announcements />
  <Awards />
</div>
```

The above is an example of how your main page would look like after you've built `Clock`, `BusSchedules`, `Announcements` and `Awards` component. They're all independent, self-contained and can be put anywhere in the page. If one breaks, the probability of the others breaking is reduced. Say I want to remove `Clock`, I'd just delete that line, and I wouldn't worry about the other components.